# Passing Route path to the children element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
<Route path="/pointandclick">
            <MyComponent />
          </Route>
```

For this piece of code, is there any way for my component to get the path of the Route that has been hit?

edit: to be more precise, let's say I want to know the string that has been hit (in this case /pointandclick) because in MyComponent I want to route between other paths, so I have to know if which path do I come from.

E.g.

```
<Route path="/pointandclick">
            <MyComponent />
          </Route>
<Route path="/draggablegame">
            <MyComponent />
          </Route>
```

and in my component I want to route on other components depending on the path. (example: if the Route that has been hit is pointandclick I want to render between game1, game2, game3 and if the Route is draggablegame I want to render between drag1, drag2, drag3 - so using the location hook might not be the best thing I think.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a simple javaścript's `window.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook returns the location object that represents the current `URL`. You can think about it like a `useState` that returns a new location whenever the `URL` changes.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function MyComponent() {
  let location = useLocation();
 console.log(location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `useLocation()`, you can get the active route. It's a hook that returns the location object that contains information about the current URL. Whenever the URL changes, a new location object will be returned.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-location-demo-7d3c3

Read on: https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-router-uselocation-hook-tutorial-and-examples/